# Content Enrichment for O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-enrichment

Can I use content enrichment for O365?

I've found some material about content enrichment but for on-prem. 
Where can I find information about CE for SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "No", but check out my session on Search Extensibility with Cory Roth from Ignite. We review an approach to extensibility in Office 365 using PowerShell. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK4124

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-search-service-description.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
`Not available to SharePoint Online customers`.
```

Developers can call out to an external content enrichment web service to change the managed properties of crawled items before they are indexed. The ability to change managed properties for items during content processing is helpful for tasks such as data cleansing, entity extraction, classification, and tagging. [Learn more about custom content processing.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj163968(v=office.15).aspx)